# What is exactly Automator's "web content" in a quick action process (gear wheel)?

Tags: automator

How can I use the output "web content"? What does it contain? What is the structure of this data? Is it a text, a list or other data?

What is the action to add here to obtain informations about the "web content"? Where is the documentation about the "web content" data? The documentation at https://www.macosxautomation.com/automator/services/index.html is useless about this question.

[image]

Sorry for the French screenshot. Here is a (automated) translation:

> The process receives the current element web content in Safari.app.
>
> The input is the whole selection. [ ] Output replaces the selected text
>
> Image Download
>
> Color Black

For example, I have tried to add this action:

[image]

But I obtain always an error:

[image]

Translation:

> Automator was not able to convert the input data into the chosen type.
>
> OK
>
> Display the process

And I cannot know more because the workflow, as a quick action triggered with the contextual menu, then Service, then name of the workflow, don't display this:
[image]

Translation:

> Results    Options
>
> 0 items   Name
>
> Run the process to see the results.

Comment: Note that the action result is web-archive data. Any action followin the Get Contents of Webpages action in a workflow must accept web content as its input data type. (http://www.macosxautomation.com/lion/webcontent/index.html)

Comment: @LorisFoe Thanks, but when I try the example "Extract Images from Selection" I obtain nothing. If I check the box "Display this action..." at "Get Folder Content" action, I obtain a "Err516.dd" error when running. I'm under Big Sur. Perhaps security settings problem? At Security System Preferences: for **Files and Folders** Downloads is checked for Automator. No way found to add Desktop (where is the documentation?). So I change Desktop to Downloads in the action. But nothing. No error, but folder empty and no image in Preview.app. What to do?

Comment: Oh no. I count at least six different questions here. If no one has an answer in a  might need some simplification so we don’t have to figure how to tie together six answers into one…

Answer (score 2):

First : it does not seem that the input type "web content" is accepted by Safari (because it does not appear under Services menu) but if we use "**no input**" in Safari it then does appear in Services menu.

**Simple example:**
This example shows how to launch a QuickAction from the Services menu in Safari.
Because the QuickAction does not get any data as input we have to fetch the Safari current web page by :

1. Get current Safari web page
2. Retrieve content of the web page
3. And finally download images

Click save, give a name and launch this new QuickAction from Services menu in Safari; it will download all images of the current web page in your computer.
[image: automator screenshot]

To conclude : for a Safari quick action don't use the web content input type it does not work (imo)

**And to answer your question** : the type "web content" is the type of data that my 2nd block returns. It can be used by any block that accepts "web content" type as input (my 3rd block is an example of that).

Comment: So the example http://www.macosxautomation.com/lion/webcontent/gfx/workflow01.png from the page http://www.macosxautomation.com/lion/webcontent/index.html don't work? It display "web content" as input with Safari (and when I try, the service appears in the Service menu). But as explained, it creates error. Must I update my first post with theses element?

Comment: No this screenshot is **outdated** (I see multiple issues/changes : between "Save Images from Web Content" and "Get Folder Contents" there was a connection (arrow and circle) but today there is no more! It simply means that an error occurs when we try to get folder contents i.e it does not know which folder in your file system to use – because nothing is communicated between these two blocks!)

Comment: So, finally to answer this subquestion, you can open the images of the current Safari web page by writing this in Automator :  https://imgur.com/JkhHdC5 As you can see now between each blocks there is a connection and data is passing between them.